# Creating hierarchical data structures in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to create a nested data structure in a Firebase that looks like this:

```
{
    things: {
        <thingId>: {
            name: 'My thing'
            sub_things: {
                <sub_thing_id>: {
                    name: 'Sub thing'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I've done this:

```
thingsRef = new Firebase('http://my.firebaseio.com/things');
thingsRef.push({name: 'My thing'});
thingsRef.child('sub_things').push({name: 'Sub thing'});
```

But `sub_things` never gets sync'd up to the server. Ideas? I want to get the local copy immediately.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are calling `.child('sub_things')` on the original `thingsRef` instead of the child you just created. Try the following:

```js
thingsRef = new Firebase('http://my.firebaseio.com/things');
var childRef = thingsRef.push({name: 'My thing'});
childRef.child('sub_things').push({name: 'Sub thing'});
```

Comment: Hm, that works but doesn't properly the `id` attribute on `sub_thing`. I end up with this:

{ subthings: { <subthing_id>: { name: 'Sub thing' } } }.

That seems to cause problems when I want to update/delete it. I think it's related to the fact that `childRef.child('sub_things').push({name: 'Sub thing'});` works but `childRef.child('sub_things').push();` doesnt

Comment: You can do `var newRef = childRef.child('sub_things').push();` followed by a `newRef.set({name: 'Sub thing'});` if you don't want to set data at the same time as calling `push`.